# Why singular "וְלֹא הָיָה מַיִם" in Bamidbar 20:2?

Tags: grammar-dikduk, water, chukas

The word מַיִם is, as far as I know, pretty consistently grammatically plural in *Chumash* (and, incidentally, in more modern Hebrew also). That is, the adjectives that modify it are plural adjectives, and the verbs of which it's the [subject](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_%28grammar%29) are plural verbs. For example, we have (Numbers 5:22) "וּבָאוּ הַמַּיִם הַמְאָרְרִים הָאֵלֶּה", "this cursed water will come", where the adjective "this" and the verb forms "cursed" and "will come" are all grammatically plural (which is why the verse is usually translated as something like "these cursed waters will come" even though that's [awkward](https://blog.udemy.com/proofreaders-symbols/) in English).

**Why does it say "וְלֹא הָיָה מַיִם לָעֵדָה", with a singular verb, in [Numbers 20:2](http://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.20.2)?**

Comment: I suspect that the plurality by sotah has to do with the multiple curses and oaths associated with it. So it's closer to "these curses (through) the water will come." Can you provide other examples that use the collective noun without appended plural nouns, but still have plural verbs and adjectives?

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky _yikavu_ (Gn 1:9) intransitive _nif'al_ verb, _yishr'tzu_ (Gn 1:20) transitive _kal_ verb, _hayu_ (Gn 7:10) intransitive _kal_ verb of the same root discussed in this question, _chayim_ (Gn 26:19) adjective, and many more

Comment: thanks! I feel these are much better examples than the one in your question. One remaining question: are there other locations using non plural adjectives and verbs? The Torah might be distinguishing between direct objects (oceans, a vessel filled with water, etc.) and conceptual water (to drink). This could be why their need is considered singular, but the water that came forth was plural...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky I don't know. Certainly the vast majority that are clearly plural or singular are plural.

Comment: Consider asking this on biblical hermeneutics too

Comment: [Rada"k uses](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/radak/radak04.pdf) the phrase "לעולם הוא לשון רבים", but then goes on to list a number of occurrences in addition to the focal one of this question in which internally plural "מים" uses a singular verb: "מֵי נִדָּה לֹא זֹרַק עָלָיו" and "יִזַּל מַיִם מִדָּלְיָו" and "וְכִי יֻתַּן מַיִם עַל זֶרַע". He explains the first of those singularities by its being "על הענין", which I guess means it fits better in context, but he doesn't elaborate how.

Answer (score 4):

This means that the word "water" is a general term. Thus, "There was no water (at all) for the congregation to drink just as in verse 5 ומים אין לשתות.  Water as in sentence 8 ונתן מימיו is considered plural because it was a constant flow of water(s). The difference is in the usage of the word as a single entity as opposed to something that is made up of a group.

The comments above are based on the way Rav Hirsch and the Art Scroll chumash traslate verses 5, and 8.

Artscroll translation

verse 3  *... and there is no water to drink!*

verse 8 *... it shall give its waters*

Also "its waters" in verse 8 uses the plural possessive rather than the singular possessive.

See also in verse 11

ויצאו מים רבים

Comment: It is not clear to me what differentiates the single entity water to which you refer from the composite. What would be a test case in which we would expect an instance of water to be treated as one or the other, everything else being equal? Is there reason to believe Artscroll was compelled _grammatically_ to use "there is no water" over "there are no waters", and not aesthetically/stylistically/Englishly?

Comment: @WAF I think that the foundation of asking this question is that the Hebrew word for water has a plural ending ("-im"). Thus, one would expect the plural to be used, as it often is in Tanac"h. This verse, is thus, an exception. I won't comment on, specifically, Art Scroll's explanation. The point is that it's often difficult to translate exactly each Hebrew word.

Answer (score 0):

1. מים is always plural in Hebrew. In Biblical Hebrew it is very common that plural is replaced with single both with the noun or the verb. Examples:

   - וַיִּֽחַן־שָׁ֥ם יִשְׂרָאֵ֖ל נֶ֥גֶד הָהָֽר - instead of ויחנו and ישראל (single) instead of בני ישראל
   - וְהָרֹג בְּשֹׂנְאֵיהֶם חֲמִשָּׁה וְשִׁבְעִים אָלֶף - not אלפים

   Similarly "לא היה מים" is identical to לא היו מים.
2. In contemporary Hebrew we use this expression independently of the subject, for example: "לא היה לי עצבים", or "לא היה לי מים להתקלח". Maybe similar to English "ain't".